# what kind of ssl cert do i need for multiple subdomains of multiple domains hosted on a reverse proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

i have an nginx reverse proxy that has multiple sub domains of mutliple domains. there is some content manipulation happening on my server, hence the need for the reverse proxy. they are all hosted on the one server with one ip address.
eg.

- example.com
- blog.example.com
- another-example.com
- shop.another-example.com

each of these sites is is hosted elsewhere and have ssl set up where necessary.

what i want to know is can i offer all these domains and sub domains over https and what sort of ssl cert do i need?

as far as i know i can use a wildcard domain cert for each parent domain, or a multi-domain cert for each fully qualified domain, but is there a simpler solution? (one that won't cost me a fortune) like:

- a cert that will verify for my one ip address
- a way i can pass the browser credentials to the destination server
- a way to authenticate as one single domain "host.nginxproxy.com"

apologies if i havent explained myself properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wildcard cert for each 2nd level domain, or a standard cert for each if you do not need multiple sub domains.

Comment: It appears to be dependent on which CA you go with but each cert must be signed by one company, and as all my clients are seperate companies, i'll need one wildcard cert for domain with subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix SAN certificates and wildcard certificates, thus creat a single certificate that can be used for all your domains. However, IMNSHO, The best way to handle this is really to assign a single IP per 2dn level domain and the use a SAN or wildcard cert for sub-domains and different hostnames.

The main reason for this is that if you try to put all your certs through the same IP, you will run into trouble when you want to add or remove a domain or host because any change to the published list will require you to request a new certificate. This can end up being pretty expensive, quite a bit more than getting a handfull of IP addresses. Also, public CAs typically limit the number of SAN that you can include in a si^ngle cert.